# Connect Raspberry 4 to a Computer

Tags: setup

I have a brand new Raspberry PI 4 but silly of me I thought it was possible to configure it and apply initial setup just connecting the raspberry to a computer, but as far as I saw, it needed an external monitor.

Is there any way to use a computer (in my case a Macbook Pro) as Raspberry PI monitor or at least is there a way to set up raspberry through a computer?

Comment: You can't connect the output HDMI on a Raspberry to the output HDMI on your Mac. What you can do is use RealVNC to share the RPi screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a way to set up raspberry through a computer?

Yes. Plug the SD-Card to your computer then add an empty file named `ssh` without any format/type to the `/boot` partition.

After that, connect raspberry pi to a network with a DHCP server that can be your modem/router. Then, the raspberry pi will get an IP address over the network. You can find the IP address by some apps on your computer or by the modem/router's web interface.
Also, in a better way, you don't need these step to find the IP address of raspberry pi. You can connect to it by `raspberrypi.local` hostname.

In the final step, you need to install an SSH client to your computer to connect to the raspberry pi's terminal over SSH protocol (On the Mac, `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`). Note that the default user is `pi` and the password is `raspberry`.

Comment: You should specify what you mean by "the" SD card, as the rest of your instructions depend on what exactly is on that SD card in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as @JBentley says, I would appreciate more details in some points

Comment: SD-Card is the same in all places. You have a Raspberry Pi 4B, a power supply to hold it on and an SD-Card to write operating system (Raspbian) data. -- Unplug the SD-Card from the raspberry pi and attach it to an SD-Card Reader then plug the SD-Card Reader to your computer. Then, you'll see SD-Card's data which has two partitions there. One of them is `/root` and another one is `/boot`. Just mount `/boot` and follow the structure above. I'll be happy if I answer your questions.

Comment: @M.Rostami "SD-Card is the same in all places" - I wasn't referring to the SD card itself, but rather the *contents* of that SD-card. Your answer states to simply put an empty file named `ssh` on a /boot partition (of what? should the user simply create a /boot partition on a blank card? Is the partition already there because e.g. an OS is pre-loaded on the card? If so which one?). Note that there are plenty of other OS choices other than Raspbian, which is why your answer is not clear unless you specify it. You should do it by editing the answer rather than leaving additional comments.

Comment: After that you can get the video output from your raspberry pi by using RealVNC (comes pre-installed on raspbian). This can be done by downloading [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/) for your mac. Then SSH into the raspberry pi and run the command `sudo raspi-config`. Go down to `Interfacing Options` then `VNC` and enable it. After that open up VNC viewer on your mac and add a new host (`cmd N`).  (VNC server is `raspberrypi.local` and the Friendly Identifier is `pi`).